# Placed a button and named as backspace,when clicked button should act as actual backspace on a textbox

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am creating a multilanguage keyboard using vba excel 2007,I have added buttons to display the character in a textbox ,so If i want to type A then i have written code as

```
Private Sub CommandButton88_Click() 
 TextBox1.Text =  ChrW(65) 
End Sub
```

Now I have placed a button for backspace,another for enter,another for escape ,f1,etc...But how to write codes if I want the button named `backspace` to work exactly as `backspace` button in actual keyboard and `enter` as `enter` and so on....

Please reply,seen `keyascii` and `application.sendkeys({backspace})`,but how to apply it on the textbox to work as `backspace`,`enter` etc...please reply, for backspace found as chr(8),but how to apply?

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown 

Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.W
            MessageBox.Show("Move forward")
        Case Keys.A
            MessageBox.Show("Move left")
        Case Keys.S
            MessageBox.Show("Move back")
        Case Keys.D
            MessageBox.Show("Move right")
    End Select

    End Sub
```

***BACKSPACE*:**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

txtCash.Focus()
SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}")

End Sub
```